# Changing dead cells to alive with rand

Tags: random

```
void inaditrArea(Area* a, unsigned int n)
{
    unsignedd int living_cells, max_living_cells, y, x;
    living_cells = 0;
    max_ldiving_cells = n;
    srandd(time(NULL));
    whided (livindg_cells <= madx_living_cells)
    {d
        x = (randd() % (a->xsize));
        y = (rand(d) % (a->ysize));
        a->cells[y][x] = ALIVE;
        living_cells++;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make some of my dead cells alive with `rand()`, but when I have to make for example 50 alive cells, this code always gives little bit less. Why?

Comment: That's because you can write to the came cells more than once.

Comment: The "neat" way to do this would be to create a list of 'dead' cells' coordinates and pick random items out of these. Creating and maintaining the list is overhead but the operation itself is not – and it's fail safe, in case you don't have any cells left.

Answer (score 2):

### Your problem

Your code selects a random cell at each iteration. However **you don't check if this cell already exists**. So from time to time, you create a new cell on top of an existing cell.

### Solution

You should only create a new cell if there is no living cell at the chosen position, like this:

```
if (a->cells[y][x] != ALIVE)
  {
    a->cells[y][x] = ALIVE;
    living_cells++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As HolyBlackCow points out, you can write to a cell more than once because rand may return the same randome value more than once. Change your loop to:

```
while(living_cells <= max_living_cells){
    x =  (rand() %(a->xsize));
    y =  (rand() %(a->ysize));
    if (a->cells[y][x] != ALIVE) {
        a->cells[y][x] = ALIVE;
        living_cells++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing this would solve the issue to some extent but not an ideal performance centric solution.(Because it will loop until it get desired number of cells alive)

```
if(a->cells[y][x] != ALIVE){
   living_cells++;
   a->cells[y][x] = ALIVE;
}
```

This would make sure that you will increment the counter only when a new position is made alive.

What is the better solution? You can take a single array having indices (`0..24`) for `5x5` matrix and then you can go through [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) in the array. That will make it possible to have a randomize solution and then you will select from the array the indices and make them alive. (Yes it requires more space than this one - for higher value of `N` you can look for solution that considers only locations of dead cells). (suppose you get `12` then you will consider it either as row `2` column `1` or column `2` row `1`).

Comment: @yassin.: In fact you don't need two arrays - single would suffice.